# How to handle performance in huge UniformGrids?

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml

I have a view in my application with huge table like data to display. The data is displayed in two nested UniformGrids. The UniformGrids are ItemPanels in ItemsControls and are bound to some ViewModels. See the following image and some example XAML-Code:

[view and viewmodel http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/8825/stackoverflowuniformgri.png](http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/8825/stackoverflowuniformgri.png)

```
<!-- The green boxes -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BigCells}">

  <ItemsControl.ItemPanel>
    <PanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid />
    </PanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemPanel>

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>

      <!-- The blue boxes -->
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SmallCells}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemPanel>
          <PanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid />
          </PanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemPanel>
      </ItemsControl>

    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now, I want my view to be resizable but this does not perform well at all since every single small box's layout is computed.
This could at least for the boxes size be done only once, since it is equal for all boxes.

What is best practice to display a huge amount of controls in WPF / where could I start optimizing? Keywords would already help me to continue discovering performance optimizations for UniformGrids in WPF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had a similar problem when using a lot of WPF `DataGrid` at the same time. It finally came down to two major issues :

- Resource dictionaries
- Bindings

**Resource Dictionaries**

Those can be major bottlenecks if you use basic WPF features without being careful.

In my case, for a single logical scroll in the `ItemsControl` that was containing my `DataGrids`, I was getting something like 10 millions call to `GetValue` and `GetValueWithoutLock` on ResourceDictionary. More than 1 second to process.

This major number of `ResourceDictionary` accesses was caused by different sources :

- Dynamic resource retrieval : If you have `ControlTemplates`, and more generally resources placed in some resource dictionaries, and you access them via `{DynamicResource ...}`, remove them. Have some static somewhere and acces them directly.
- Style fetching : If you have no style on the different Visual you use, or if you have a Style but didn't set the [FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.overridesdefaultstyle.aspx) property, WPF will try to find a style matching the control in all the resources, which result in a lot of accesses to resources dictionaries. To avoid that, be sure to override all of the control templates of your controls, and set `Style={x:Null}` on each and every control (if you need a style for a control, set it inline on your control, and add `OverridesDefaultStyle = true`)
- Implicit DataTemplates : Implicit data template are very usefull but are far from free to. When looking for a `DataTemplate` to apply, WPF will once again browse your resource dictionaries to find a `DataTemplate` matching your ViewModels types. Solution is to use a `DataTemplate` selector for each and every control binded to a ViewModel, and implement an optimized way to retrieve the correct `DataTemplate`. (I personally have some static fields for my dataTemplate that I retrieve only once from a resourceDictionary, and an optimized `DataTemplateSelector` that returns them as needed.)

**Bindings**

Bindings are very useful, but very expensive, memory wise and performance wise. In a very sensible environement - from a performance point of view - you can't just use them without being carefull. For exmample, binding can create up to 3 WeakReferences for each binded object, can use reflection, etc. I finally ended up with removing almost all of my binding and plugged event handler on my DataContext's PropertyChanged event. When `DataContext` changes on my Controls (you have a `DataContextChanged` event) I test if my `DataContext` supports `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and if it's the case,  I attach an event handler on `PropertyChanged` event and update properties as needed. (I only had one way bindings, so this is why I chose this way of doing things, but there are other solutions).

It can seems frustrating not using bindings when using MVVM and WPF, but there was actually no way to optimize bindings in my case.

Last thing : if you have `Freezable` objects (like Brushes for example), don't hesitate to `Freeze` them if you can.

Those are some advices that can help you optimizing your code. You will need a profiler (I always advice using dotTrace as this is the best profiler I ever used) to monitor what's really happening and adapt your according to the results.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It already contains some points I can improve in my application (freezables, default style override). I will check this out and report later.

Comment: Sure, let me know how it goes ! It was actually a good exercise for me as I have to write a performance post on my blog :)

Comment: We have lots of resource dictionaries for everything and the application is still very fast. The way we approached it was creating one resource dictionary for one resource (like style, vector, brush etc), then from each view we only reference those resource dictionaries which are needed. The problem is the uniform grid itself, because it does not virtualize.

Answer (score 5):

If you're sure about all the boxes wanting to be the same size, you could always make your own `UniformGrid` class and override `MeasureOverride` to measure only one child. I could end up with some large UniformGrids with same-size internal controls in my current project too, so your idea intrigued me and I decided to try it out really quick:

I used Petzold's [UniformGridAlmost](ftp://ftp.charlespetzold.com/AppsCodeMarkup/Chapter%2012/DuplicateUniformGrid/UniformGridAlmost.cs) class as inspiration, but subclassed from `UniformGrid` instead of `Panel` so the Rows and Columns depdendency properties don't need to be duplicated. `UniformGrid` doesn't appear to publicize the computed number of rows and columns to its derived classes, so I borrowed an implementation from [Silverlight's UniformGrid class](http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/10444748) and used the `UpdateComputedValues` method.

The `MeasureOverride` in my class looks like this

```
  protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size sizeAvailable)
  {
     if (InternalChildren.Count == 0)
     {
        return new Size(0, 0);
     }

     UpdateComputedValues();

     // Calculate a child size based on uniform rows and columns.
     Size sizeChild = new Size(sizeAvailable.Width / ComputedColumns,
                               sizeAvailable.Height / ComputedRows);

     // Assume children will measure to at least a comparable size.
     UIElement child = InternalChildren[0];
     child.Measure(sizeChild);

     double width = Math.Max(width, child.DesiredSize.Width);
     double height = Math.Max(height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
     return new Size(ComputedColumns * width, ComputedRows * height);
  }
```

So, here's the kicker, when I tested it on an ItemsControl with 10000 TextBlocks, my version of UniformGrid was faster, but only by a tiny amount (less than 1% - I confirmed that the call to MeasureOverride is about 95% faster). So this is probably not helpful, but I thought I would share my experience. Your observation that it doesn't need to measure every box to determine the uniform layout in your case is true, but that measuring isn't what's bogging it down. I'm sure that's because all those controls still need to be drawn, so they'll be measured later anyway. You're going to get a lot more out of the ResourceDictionary/Binding suggestion most likely.

Comment: I just tried this  UniformGridAlmost as is, and in my case it is about 3 times quicker than the standard uniform grid. So the drawing time dropped from 20seconds to about 7seconds.

Comment: Interesting that with this implementation I also saw an improvement on the Measure phase but it seems to cause more processing when it starts to Arrange. So as an example I was seeing 127ms in Measure, and 30ms in Arrange. With this change it goes to 52ms in Measure (Yay!), but up to 184ms in Arrange (Boo!) so I actually saw a loss of performance by 79ms.